# Sending health expenses to the health card system (in Italy)

Tags: web-services, soap, chilkat

Someone using ChilKat's ActiveX (or something similar) managed to use the EsitoInvioDatiSpesa730Service or EsitoInvioDatiSpesa730Service endpoints made available by the Healthcare Card System (in Italy).
I can send the data using the aforementioned ActiveX but I cannot understand how to create the SOAP request to know the outcome of the consignments.
Thanks for your help

*** EDIT 07/01/2020

Those are the WSDL URLs and XSD schemas for the SOAP service:

CSV TYPE ERROR REQUEST
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/tree/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/DettaglioErrori-CSV
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/blob/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/DettaglioErrori-CSV/DettaglioErrori730Service_schema.xsd

SERVICE REQUEST SEND OUTCOME
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/blob/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/EsitoInvio/EsitoInvioDatiSpesa730Service.wsdl
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/blob/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/EsitoInvio/EsitoInvioDatiSpesa730Service_schema.xsd

REQUEST FOR RECEIPT PDF RECEIPTS
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/blob/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/RicevutoPDF/RicevutaPdf730Service.wsdl
https://github.com/BigNerd95/STSClient/blob/master/STSClient/resources/wsdl/WS_Ricevute/RicevutoPDF/RicevutaPdf730Service_schema.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a WSDL URL for the SOAP service?  Without the specification, it's impossible for anyone to help with this kind of request.

Comment: I entered the WSDL URLs and XSD schemas for the SOAP service in the first post. Thank you